# PHP парсинг текста между числами с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Делаю парсинг текста. Текст представляет из себя даты и описание даты. Мне нужно получить каждую дату с описанием в отдельности, чтобы их потом отформатировать.

Код с исходным текстом такой:

```
$c = '1977 — пожар в московской гостинице «Россия», в результате которого погибло 42 человека 1992 — создано Российское космическое агентство 1994 — Барух Гольдштейн совершил теракт в пещере Патриархов';
preg_match_all('/\d+\s—\D+/',$c, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Шаблон /\d+\s—\D+/ делает почти то, что нужно, но если в описании даты встречается число, то текст обрезается.
Помогите написать правильно регулярное выражение, чтобы выбрать из текста в массив строки, начиная с даты, т.е. print_r должен вернуть:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1977 — пожар в московской гостинице «Россия», в результате которого погибло 42 человека
            [1] => 1994 — Барух Гольдштейн совершил теракт в пещере Патриархов
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```php
/\b\d{4}\s—.*?(?=\s+\d{4}\s—|$)/su
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oRqdM3/4).

*Подробности*:

- `\b` - граница слова
- `\d{4}` - четыре цифры
- `\s` - пробельный символ
- `—` - символ `—`
- `.*?` - ноль и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `(?=\s+\d{4}\s—|$)` - позиция в строке, сразу после которой следуют один и более пробельных символов, четыре цифры и тире (`\s+\d{4}\s—`) или конец строки (`$`).

[Пример работы кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/AAHuZ):

```php
$re = '/\b\d{4}\s—.*?(?=\s+\d{4}\s—|$)/su';
$str = '1977 — пожар в московской гостинице «Россия», в результате которого погибло 42 человека 1992 — создано Российское космическое агентство 1994 — Барух Гольдштейн совершил теракт в пещере Патриархов';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1977 — пожар в московской гостинице «Россия», в результате которого погибло 42 человека
    [1] => 1992 — создано Российское космическое агентство
    [2] => 1994 — Барух Гольдштейн совершил теракт в пещере Патриархов
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант рабочий!

Comment: @Y.G. если ответ дает решение на поставленный вами вопрос, то следует его отметить как правильный нажав зеленую галочку слева от ответа.